# Como setar um max-width a uma div que aumenta e diminui proporcionalmente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Minha `div` que aumenta ou diminui proporcionalmente está com estilo de:

```
padding-bottom: 75%;
```

Olhem esse exemplo: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/5UpGK/)

*O que eu quero é que a `div` que cresce proporcionalmente trave o tamanho, quando encostar no rodapé. Senão fizer isso, ela cresce infinitamente.*

Alguma solução?

---

**Screens:**
[image: primeira imagem]
Primeira fase esta ok.

[image: segunda imagem]
Nessa segunda imagem, perceba que ele encostou no rodapé, ou seja, é pra ele travar com esse tamanho ficando como a terceira imagem.

[image: terceira imagem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veja o resultado no **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/Sy3Mw/)**, utilizando Javascript puro para manipular as propriedades CSS do elemento slide.

Note que a propriedade `padding-bottom: 75%;` da classe slide foi **removida**, uma vez que as dimensões do slide são controladas por script.

Abaixo, segue o script que realiza a tarefa:

```
var slide = document.querySelector('.slide'); 

var aspectRatio = 720/540;  // ou (4:3) proporção de aspecto do div .slide

function resize() {
    // dimensões da janela disponíveis
    var newHeight = document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 39; // 39 é o espaço ocupado pelo footer
    var newWidth = 0.8 * (document.documentElement.offsetWidth); // largura disponível: 80% do documento
    var newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;

    // ajusta o div mantendo as proporções de aspecto definidas por aspectRatio      
    if (newWidthToHeight > aspectRatio) {
      newWidth = newHeight * aspectRatio;
    } else {
      newHeight = newWidth / aspectRatio;
    } 
    slide.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
    slide.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}

// efetua um redimensionamento inicial
resize();

// redimensiona o slide sempre que a janela for redimensionada
window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);

// (!) utilize a função resize sempre que o div .slide sofrer alterações
```

Sempre que um elemento precisar ser redimensionado de acordo com uma proporção de aspecto("*aspect ratio*"- em inglês), pode-se utilizar uma estratégia semelhante.

Não sei se é possível conseguir os mesmos resultados através de `CSS Media Queries` ou outra estratégia que utilize puramente CSS, mas caso seja possível prefira sempre o uso de CSS.

Comment: Observação: O script acima não é 100% cross-browser, uma vez que `querySelector` e `document.documentElement.offsetWidth` podem não estar disponíveis em navegadores mais antigos mas é bem simples ajustá-lo conforme a necessidade, podendo por exemplo utilizar jQuery, caso já o utilize no documento em questão. =)

Comment: perfeito @GustavoCarvalho, só um probleminha. O body esta com uma margin, como a removo? Coloquei um margin:0 nele, só que dai o slide fica com um espaço entre a lateral direita.

Comment: Outra coisa, vou ter duas classes slide e só funciona na primeira.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, Para remover a margem do body basta adicionar no CSS do body `margin: 0 0 0 0;` Mas aí tem que ajustar no script em `newWidth`(o desconto de 16 era dado por conta da margem, confira a resposta atualizada). Para mais de um slide basta dividir a altura disponível pelo número de slides. Confira [neste FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcarv/Jkf2x/).

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso você terá que usar algumas coisas e um pouco de matemática.

Você pode pegar o tamanho dos elementos de 3 formas:

1. `$(ele).height` - Não contabiliza as medidas do padding, border e margin;
2. `$(ele).innerHeight` - Não contabiliza as medidas do border e margin, mas contabiliza o padding;
3. `$(ele).outerHeight` - Não contabiliza as medidas da margin por padrão, mas aceita um parâmetro que permite contabilizar;

Sabendo disso, você pode obter o tamanho do window (viewport) ou do document (página inteira). A diferença entre os dois é que window é o tamanho da área visível no browser e document é da página toda, mesmo dos elementos escondidos por conta da posição.

Com essas informações, basta você definir uma regra (e um momento para executar essa regra) onde seu código avalie o tamanho do viewport ou do document e estabeleça o max-height do elemento que não pode crescer demais.

Você pode executar a função por exemplo toda vez que algo for escrito naquele elemento, ou apenas no `DOMReady` da página.

Answer (score 1):

O **melhor modo** de fazer isso é usar **CSS media queries**, não javascript. Por favor, evitem sugerir fazer em javascript algo que pode ser feito em CSS puro. Javascript adiciona complexidade adicional e deve ser evitada caso exista meios mais simples.

É mais simples e funciona em todo lugar, e mesmo quando não funcionar e o desenvolvedor fizer questão de que funcione em navegadores antigos como IE8, também seria necessário javascript para forçar o funcionamento.

Em https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries tem um guia bom sobre Media Queries.

Um exemplo muito curto a respeito disso:

```
/* entre 1024px e 1200px uma barra lateral seria ocultada */
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1200px){
    .sidebar-b {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Concordo plenamente que se deve usar CSS quando der para usar. Mas neste caso não vejo como não usar JS. Pode tentar dar um exemplo com CSS usando o __[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/5UpGK/)__ do Jefferson?

Comment: Se o @Jefferson Alison informar os pontos de quebra e  o seletor dos elementos a serem quebrados, faço sim.

Comment: @EmersonRochaLuiz, você diz os pontos de quebra tipo: "ah la em 1024px de width esta quebrando, la em 1200px está quebrando" ?

Comment: Ex: w > 0 && w <= 768px: Imagem 1; w > 768px && w < 1200px: imagem 2; e assim por diante onde w é largura da tela em `px` ou `em` (caso use `em`)